# mvn --version -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set

Tags: maven-3

I have downloaded and installed maven3.3.3. on uBuntu 14.04 and when I run the command

```
mvn --version
```

I get this error

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME `enter code here`environment variable and mvn script match.
```

I have tries to set the enviroment in /etc/environment

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin"

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre"

MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Dmaven.surefire.debug=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

M2_HOME="/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3"
```

your help will be greatly appreciated

G

Comment: in a terminal or in an IDE?

Comment: in the terminal @A.B.

Comment: Does my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In a terminal*

```
./mvn -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME --version
```

*In Eclipse*

<kbd>Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Edit</kbd>

Add the line below into *Default VM arguments*

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
```

---

Per default, there is nothing to do:

```
cd
wget http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz
tar xf apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz
cd apache-maven-3.3.3/bin
./mvn --version
```

---

*Example output*

```
$ ./mvn --version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
Maven home: /home/aboettger/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-21-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```